# Exclude time value from JUnit failure reports

Tags: ant, junit

Is there a way to customise the failure report from junit such that I can remove the time value from the test results? First prize - a way to do this without having to write code; second prize - knowing that there is no other option.

At first I thought this was an Ant thing, but looking at the

```
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitResultFormatter
```

interface, it seems like the only thing I can control here is where the output goes, not what the actual output is. Ok - I could edit the output before allowing it out, but I could also just write a script to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint, but you have to write code.  Either XSLT to create a different report or post processing HTML code.